# How to add One year to a date in python?

Tags: python, python-datetime

I am comparing two dates with each other from two excels
I need to make a condition by comparing one of the dates to the other by increasing it by one year
following is my code:

```
date1=str(ws1["H2"].value).strip()
date2=str(ws2["H2"].value).strip()

for p in date1.splitlines():
    d=parser.parse(p)
    date1=d.strftime("%d.%m.%Y")
date1=parser.parse(date1,dayfirst=True)
print(date1)

date2=parser.parse(date2,dayfirst=True)
print(date2)


if date1<date2:
    print('matched')
else:
    print('not matched')
```

The code is working fine
What i want to do is ,sometimes i want to check whether date1 is still less than date2 after adding 1 year to date2. How do i do that??

I want to add 1 year to date2 and then again compare if date1 is less than date2 or not

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `dateutil.relativedelta.relativedelta`

**Ex:**

```
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

while date2 < date1:    #Check if date2 is less that date1
    date2 += relativedelta(years=1)   #increment date2
```

Answer (score 1):

You can *replace* any individual part of a datetime object:

```
if date1 < date2.replace(year = date2.year):
    ...
```